# How do I prevent Adobe's pdf reader from opening a pdf within firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I've installed adobe's pdf reader.

However, now when I download a pdf using firefox, often adobe's reader loads the pdf in a firefox reader.

How do I set the default behaviour to storing the pdf, rather then loading it within firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go to about:addons, select "Plugins" and disable the adobe reader plugin:

[image: Adobe plugin disabled]

There is also another option, which is a bit more complicated:

- Go to Edit->Preferences->Applications
- Type pdf in the filter box
  [image: pdf in filter box]
- Choose to "save file" by default instead of opening with the default plugin

Comment: Thanks. Disabling the addon was what I needed to know. I don't need another application to be added for handling the files. I'm happy just downloading pdf and opening them with whatever the desktop environment default application is. Cheers.